# Numpy sort works oddly

Tags: python, numpy

I have a massive `data = np.array([1000, 2500, 1400, 1800, 900, 4200, 2200, 1900, 3500])`. I need to append an user input and sort data.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1000, 2500, 1400, 1800, 900, 4200, 2200, 1900, 3500])

new_data = input()
data = np.append(data, new_data)
data = np.sort(data)
print(data)
```

Without append i have normal sorted array, but when i use it i have that

```
['1000' '1400' '1800' '1900' '2200' '2500' '3500' '4200' '654' '900']
```

I noticed that xxx number appear in the end of the list. xxxx digit as an input appears where it should be

```
['1000' '1400' '1800' '1900' '2200' '2222' '2500' '3500' '4200' '900']
```

Comment: It's not the `sort` that's giving problems.  Look at `data` after the `append`.  And a `new_data` before that.

Comment: The new data inputs are strings, so the combined data is sorted as strings. Convert them to numbers before appending them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type of `Input()` is a string. This is why when you append it to the array, it considers each element as a string and sorts them by the first alphabet and then subsequent ones.

Check data type before and after -

```
#BEFORE APPENDING - 
>>type(data[3])
numpy.int64

#AFTER APPENDING - 
>>type(data[3])
numpy.str_
```

Instead, convert the input to `int` or `float` first -

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1000, 2500, 1400, 1800, 900, 4200, 2200, 1900, 3500])

new_data = int(input()) #<---- Look here!
data = np.append(data, new_data)
data = np.sort(data)
print(data)
```

```
2222
[ 900 1000 1400 1800 1900 2200 2222 2500 3500 4200]
```